Car taking long cranks to start
I have Renault Duster 1.6 K4M petrol 2015 model. The problem with the car is it takes long cranks to start, the speed of cranking is normal but it takes longer to start the engine. Also the acceleration is poor at low RPMs around 1500-1700 RPM there is lag. When the engine starts it vibrates a lot but gets smooth once it starts. There is no visible smoke from tailpipe and battery is also new. The car has run 72K KMs and just around 3-4K KMs this problem has cropped up.

Does it take a long time to start when the engine is warm, or does it start right away?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Thanks, it takes relatively longer to start when the engine is warm compared to cold starts.

When are spark plugs, air and fuel filter recommended for replacement?

Everything was changed recently.

Have you ever tried turning on the ignition to get instrument lights but not cranking, and waiting about 10 seconds, then cranking to start? Does it start quickly when you do that? If you have never tried it, please try and let us know.

Yes I have tried that. I waited for for 10 seconds but still took long cranking to start.

After you start the car, does the "check engine" light remain lit or does it turn off? It looks like this on your Duster, possibly on the tachometer: https://www.financialexpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/check-engine-light-480x320.jpg

Hard starting may be as simple as either a spark or fuel issue, or as complicated as a map, maf, vacuum leak problem. Do you know what fuel pressure should be on the injector rail? Can you test for spark, pulling a spark plug? Can you spray starting fluid into the throttle body to see if the engine starts up immediately?

After car starts there is no check engine light. Looking for fueling related issues now. Will update when this issue resolves

With only 72k KM, the most likely problem is deposits.  A fuel cleaner is in order.  The very best one available is BG 44k.  Use one can with a petrol fill-up for three consecutive tankfuls, combined with an enzyme treatment such as Formula 9X.  Be sure to drive in a spirited manner, with plenty of very steady, highway driving.  After a month, change the crankcase oil.
